# Ao executar o POST passando objeto via URI de uma WebAPI, o objeto chega como nulo no método

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, rest, asp.net-web-api

Estou a alguns dias batendo cabeca com esse problema eu tenho uma aplicacao MVC5 fronted e ela manda um objeto para uma outra aplicacao WebAPI em um metodo Save().

Veja o codigo de minha aplicacao Frontend que envia o objeto para a WebAPI

```
public bool Add(UsuarioDto model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model,Formatting.Indented);
                var httpContent      = new StringContent(serializedObject, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var uriWebApi        = String.Concat(UriBase, "Usuario/Save");

                var response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uriWebApi, serializedObject).Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var task = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<UsuarioDto>();
                    task.Wait();
                    model = task.Result;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Model"] = model;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

E aqui esta o metodo Save da WebAPI que recebe o objeto do frontend ele chega como vazio ou null.

```
[HttpPost]
    public UsuarioDto Save(UsuarioDto model)
    {
        try
        {
           var usuarioDomain = new Usuario();
            usuarioDomain.SaveAsync(model);
            return (model);
        }
        catch 
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
```

Ja tentei colocar antes do objeto [FromBody] e [FromUri] e nada.
meu problema esta sendo em enviar objetos para a URI salvar ou editar em fim.
Quando chamo uma listagem de objeto em JSON para meu frontend esta tudo OK.
Mas para enviar nao consigo.

ja usei

httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync
httpClient.PostAsync

Se alguem puder me ajudar! fico grato!

Abracos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve passar o objeto original para a chamada, ao invés de serializar manualmente, pois o próprio método `PostAsJsonAsync` já vai serializar. Do jeito que você está mostrando, ele iria serializar algo que já tinha sido serializado.

Além disso, evite **deadlocks** no teu código, transforme teu método em `async` e utilize o `await` em todas as chamadas assíncronas:

```
var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uriWebApi, model);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    model = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<UsuarioDto>();
```

...ou se você não quiser mudar teu método para `async`, faça as chamadas dessa forma para não causar os deadlocks:

```
var response = Task.Run(async() => await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uriWebApi, model)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    model = Task.Run(async() => await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<UsuarioDto>()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Não há necessidade de utilizar `[FromBody]` nem `[FromUri]` nos teus exemplos.